# InfluxDb on Kubernetes with TLS ingress

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

I'm setting up influxdb2 on a kubernetes cluster using helm. I have enabled ingress and it works ok on port 80, but when I enable TLS and set the "secretName" to an existing TLS secret on kubernetes it times out on port 443. Is my assumption that "secretName" in the helm chart refers to a kubernetes cluster secret? Or is it a secret within influxdb itself? I can't find any useful documentation about this.

Comment: Could you add information about Kubernetes version? Did you enabled ingress with TLS support in [values.yaml](https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/blob/6fbbae850afb4a9f16ef4a50a2aafd01e79a6271/charts/influxdb/values.yaml#L167)?

Comment: More information about [Chart configuring](https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/blob/f1fde8a3d1d47e3d440bdfb679d57c13f7930711/charts/influxdb/README.md#configure-the-chart)

Comment: Hi @AndrewSkorkin, the Kubernetes version is 1.21.1 (on Amazon EKS).  TLS is enabled in values.yaml. Ingress class is application load balancer (alb).

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference to a new Kubernetes secret that is going to be created corresponding to the tls cert. It does not have to reference an existing secret. If you run `kubectl get secrets` after a successful apply , you would see a secret something like `<cert-name>-afr5d`

Comment: Thanks. I have already created the TLS cert secret, and set the secretName in the influxdb chart to match, but it's timing out. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot? For the TLS secret, I have set the cert and key properties. The cert includes the CA bundle. I'm using the helm chart here: https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/influxdb2 and it doesn't appear to create the secret so I guess it needs an existing one?

Comment: Just a thought, is influxdb expecting the secret to be a single string, rather than a TLS-type secret with its separate cert and key properties?